# Приложение has stopped при изменении темы приложения

Tags: android

Поменял параметр parent с

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

на

```
@android:style/Theme.Material.Light
```

и приложение стало вылетать [скрин](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OdtznuBu5QtenKOnEQIoJXo_Y3l-AXZc)

Стектрейс:

```
03-18 11:27:50.941 19843-19843/com.navesilli.sergey.bitsandpizzas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.navesilli.sergey.bitsandpizzas, PID: 19843
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.navesilli.sergey.bitsandpizzas/com.navesilli.sergey.bitsandpizzas.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:354)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:323)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                                    at com.navesilli.sergey.bitsandpizzas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Строка MainActivity.java:11

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

[Скрин](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1h5SmLg7dzyfhbclnehP3HtZuPXun43yA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

при наследовании от `AppCompatActivity` можно использовать только тему *AppCompat*. Если вы хотите использовать нативные темы из API Android, то вам нужно наследовать свои активити от класса `Activity`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
```